# How to add a input program in the form of (A2 5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have created a board for a binary puzzle(its random for now but it will make more sense when I add the rules)
for now I need to have a way for someone to change a value in the nested lists, this input needs to be in the format A2 4, which changes the value on the grid A2 to a 4.

```
def make_board(grid_size):
    max_headers = ["{ }", "{A}", "{B}", "{C}", "{D}", "{E}", "{F}", "{G}", "{H}", "{I}", "{J}"]
    headers = []

    for x in range(0, grid_size + 1):
        headers.append(max_headers[x])

    board = [headers]

    choices = [" 0 ", " 1 ", " . "]

    for x in range(0, grid_size):
        row = ['{' + str(x) + '}']

        for i in range(0, grid_size):
            c = random.choice(choices)
            row.append(c)

        board.append(row)

    for score in board:
        print(*score)
```

I expect the output from A2 5 to change the value of A2 on the grid to a 5

Comment: I've updated my answer -- the numbers were not being added to the correct place on the board

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your list `board` outside the method and then you can make changes to it using a different method by indexing it:

```
import random

board = []

headers = []

choices = [" 0 ", " 1 ", " . "]

max_headers = ["{ }", "{A}", "{B}", "{C}", "{D}", "{E}"]

letter_value_map = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5}

def make_board(grid_size):    
    for x in range(0, grid_size + 1):
        headers.append(max_headers[x])

    board.append(headers)

    for x in range(0, grid_size):
        row = ['{' + str(x) + '}']

        for i in range(0, grid_size):
            c = random.choice(choices)
            row.append(c)

        board.append(row)

def show_board():
    for score in board:
        print(*score)
    print()

def change_board(coord, value):
    board[int(coord[1]) + 1][letter_value_map[coord[0]]] = " " + str(value) + " "

make_board(3)
show_board()
change_board('B0', 5)
show_board()

# { } {A} {B} {C}
# {0}  1   1   0
# {1}  1   .   0
# {2}  .   0   0

# { } {A} {B} {C}
# {0}  1   5   0
# {1}  1   .   0
# {2}  .   0   0
```